# Create Trigger from Delphi Code using Native Client Driver

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi, delphi-xe2, dbexpress

I have an insert trigger that contains dynamic sql stored as a resource for my XE2 project. It also contains placeholders for the database name and table name that are substituted when the Delph code runs to execute the SQL.

Originally I was using the DevArt SQL Server driver against a SqlExpress database, but am now wanting to use ODBC and the SQL Native Client driver against a LocalDB database.

What I have found is that my original create trigger scripts no longer work.

I am using TSQLQuery.ExecSQL to execute my SQL commands.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[#TableName#_INSERT_TRIGGER] ON [#DatabaseName#].[dbo].[#TableName#] FOR INSERT
```

causes a

**'[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot create trigger on 'EvaluationCompany_COPYDB.dbo.COPY_PRODUCTS' as the target is not in the current database.'**

The parser class I use does split SQL scripts at the GO keyword into separate statements, so I amended my create trigger script to say

```
USE [#DatabaseName#]
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[#TableName#_INSERT_TRIGGER] ON [dbo].[#TableName#] FOR INSERT
```

which is what you would do in SSMS but that says

**'[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The object 'dbo.COPY_PRODUCTS' does not exist or is invalid for this operation.'**

Probably because the "current database" for the CREATE is not the one set by USE, as it seems to be forgotten.

I tried my usual way of stringing sql statements into a single execute by doing

```
USE [#DatabaseName#];
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[#TableName#_INSERT_TRIGGER] ON [dbo].[#TableName#] FOR INSERT
```

but that throws the expected

**'[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]'CREATE TRIGGER' must be the first statement in a query batch.'**

So I wrapped the whole CREATE...END in a EXEC [#DatabaseName#].[sys].[sp_ExecuteSQL] N' ' and tried to execute that. If I paste the contents of the string variable into SSMS it executes fine, but when passed to the ExecSQL, it says

**'[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The request for procedure 'sp_executesql' failed because 'sp_executesql' is a procedure object.'**

which is kind of nonsensical. So now I am at a loss as to how to create a trigger on a table using dbExpress and the SQL Server native client.

Comment: Just a sanity check, make sure you use the right database, the table exists, and check ownership of the table match with the user you used to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what the problem is, but I was able to successfully run the following code.
Maybe it will give you a clue.

```
uses
  Data.Win.AdoDB;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  aConnection : tAdoConnection;

  procedure InitializeAdoConnection;
  begin
    aConnection := tAdoConnection . Create ( self );

    with aConnection do
      begin
        ConnectionString :=   'Provider=MSDASQL.1;'
                            + 'Password=' + gPassword + ';'
                            + 'Persist Security Info=True;'
                            + 'User ID=' + gUserName + ';'
                            + 'Data Source=' + gOdbcAlias + ';'
                            + 'Extended Properties="DSN=' + gOdbcAlias + ';'
                            + 'UID=' + gUserName + ';'
                            + 'PWD=' + gPassword + ';'
                            + 'APP=Enterprise;'
                            + 'WSID=' + gMachineName + ';'
                            + 'DATABASE=master";'
                            + 'Initial Catalog=master';
        LoginPrompt := false;
        Connected := true;
      end;
  end;

  procedure ExecuteCommand ( const nSqlCommand : string );
  begin
    with tAdoCommand . Create ( nil ) do
      try
        Connection := aConnection;
        CommandText := nSqlCommand;
        Execute;
      finally
        Free;
      end;
  end;

  procedure QueryResults;
  begin
    with tAdoQuery . Create ( nil ) do
      try
        Connection := aConnection;
        SQL . Text := 'select * from COPY_PRODUCTS';
        Open;

        while not EOF do
          begin
            Memo1 . Lines . Add ( 'ID='
                  + inttostr ( FieldByName ( 'PRODUCT_ID' ) . AsInteger )
                  + ' Name='
                  + FieldByName ( 'PRODUCT_NAME' ) . AsString );

            Next;
          end;


      finally
        Free;
      end;
  end;

begin
  InitializeAdoConnection;

//  ExecuteCommand ( 'drop database EvaluationCompany_COPYDB' );

  ExecuteCommand ( 'create database EvaluationCompany_COPYDB' );

  ExecuteCommand ( 'use EvaluationCompany_COPYDB' );

  ExecuteCommand ( 'create table dbo.COPY_PRODUCTS '
                   + '( PRODUCT_ID int identity(1,1),'
                   + '  PRODUCT_NAME varchar(50) )' );

  ExecuteCommand ( 'create trigger dbo.COPY_PRODUCTS_INSERT_TRIGGER '
                   + 'on dbo.COPY_PRODUCTS '
                   + 'for insert '
                   + 'as '
                   + 'begin '
                   + '  update COPY_PRODUCTS '
                   + '    set PRODUCT_NAME = PRODUCT_NAME + ''!'' '
                   + '    where PRODUCT_ID in '
                   + '    ( select PRODUCT_ID from INSERTED )'
                   + 'end ' );

  ExecuteCommand ( 'insert into COPY_PRODUCTS ( product_name ) '
                   + 'values ( ''Stacky Goodness'' ) ' );

  QueryResults;
end;
```

Comment: Using TADOConnection and TADOCommand did work, where-as using TSQLConnection and TSQLQuery did not. Unfortunately, I was initially limited to using the existing classes to execute my trigger scripts, hence my struggles.